# Ubuntu touch in mobile?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Am using ubuntu on my computer, am a great fan of ubuntu. Am also thinking to install ubuntu touch on my mobile phones. Am using LG nexus 5 and Samsung s7 edge, It is possible to install ubuntu touch in these mobiles, if yes how can I install? please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this official Ubuntu [page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) for more info.

Comment: also this unofficial project: https://ubports.com/